# How can I edit plot placement within a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, canvas, tkinter

I'm using the following code in order to have an active plot:

```
pressure_fig= Figure(figsize=(11,6))
sensor_graph = pressure_fig.add_subplot(111)

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

sensor_graph.plot([], [])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(pressure_fig,graph_frame)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, graph_frame)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(anchor='w')
```

Which gives me [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYE2V.png).  As you can see, the Legend is partially cut off and there is a bit of gray space on the side. However, when I attempt to increase the figure size to `pressure_fig= Figure(figsize=(12,6))`, I get the [same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad0Gm.png). I  also tried, when packing it onto the screen, using [canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG5Sf.png), but this results in the same thing as using a 12x6 figure. Is there a way to force the plot to not be in the center of the canvas?

Comment: Check [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317).

Comment: That's what I had been referencing and it didn't help unfortunately

Comment: There is no attempt shown in the question, so one cannot guess what you did wrong.

Comment: Try `canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(ipadx=100)`.  You can adjust the value to fit your case.  Also is `canvas._tkcanvas.pack(...)` redundant?

Comment: Or you can use `sensor_graph.legend(loc='best')` to let matplotlib to choose the best position for the legend.

Comment: @acw1668 It's a live plot so using `loc='best'` has the potential to have the legend hop all around. As for `canvas._tkcanvas.pack(...)` being redundant, I'm not entirely sure, I was following another thread's lead on how to embed the graph so I just threw it in there